# Randomly rotate an image through right angles

Tags: python-3.x, graphics, pytorch, type-hinting

I'm new to Python, and coming from Typescript, I tried to include types, but it's not obvious sometimes.

Currently this is the way I type objects:

- Write own simple types
- Import type from a library like torch.Tensor below
- Use `typing` package for anything that looks not obvious to build the types of

```py
import torch
from typing import Optional, List, Tuple, Union

def rotate_image(
    image: torch.Tensor, is_passive_image: bool
) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, Optional[int]]:
    """
    Args:
        image (torch.Tensor): The input image tensor.
        is_passive_image (bool): A boolean value indicating whether the image is passive or active.
    Returns:
        The transformed image tensor and the rotation value (if the image is active).
    """
    if not is_passive_image:
        rand_rot = int(torch.randint(4, size=(1,)).item())
        angle = rand_rot * 90
        image = transforms.functional.rotate(image, angle)
        return image, rand_rot
    else:
        return image, 0
```

I would appreciate any comments regarding the use of types and the commenting of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## types are for documentation

> tried to include types

You did great.

Please understand that type hint annotations are entirely optional,
though the Gentle Reader will *love* them.
The cPython interpreter essentially ignores type hints.
If you *do* write them,
definitely [run](https://pypi.org/project/mypy) the `$ mypy *.py` linter so you benefit from its warnings.
(Often it turns out that
`$ mypy --no-namespace-packages --ignore-missing-imports *.py`
produces the results I find most helpful.)

---

## modern typing

```
from typing import ... List, Tuple, Union
```

Maybe you were reading a somewhat dated tutorial?
Or for some reason you need to run a downrev cPython interpreter like 3.7?

With modern interpreter, prefer the more concise:

```
def foo(xs: list[int], y: tuple[str, int|str]) -> None:
```

It's almost always more readable to express the notion of `Union[a, b]`
using `a | b` syntax.

The `Optional` symbol you imported is still in common use.
We prefer the `Optional[int]` that you wrote
over `int | None`.

Your `image: torch.Tensor` annotation is very nice,
but I wonder if we could *also* reveal the type of
data lurking within that tensor.

---

## docstring conventions

```
    """
    Args:
    ...
```

Thank you for supplying an optional docstring, it is appreciated.

Convention is to begin each docstring with a single sentence,
optionally followed by blank line and other stuff.
Please start with `"""Returns a rotated copy of the input image."""`

---

## combined condition

```
    if not is_passive_image:
```

This "maybe it's a no-op?" expression does not appear to be pulling its weight.

Consider having the caller evaluate it instead.
No need to request a rotate if caller already knows it's a no-op.
As it stands, the Public API is being made more complex
for little apparent gain.

```
        return image, rand_rot
```

It appears to me that 25% of the time this, too, is a no-op.

If you do not take the previous advice about
deleting the `is_passive_image` parameter,
then consider constructing a `bool` condition
based on that plus whether the random rotation is `0`.
Then the `if` just looks at that boolean.
Goal is to avoid calling a possibly expensive identity function.

---

## optional ?

```
    ... -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, Optional[int]]:
```

No.

100% of the time we return an `int`
in the range `0` .. `3`.
It is definitely not an `Optional` return type.

---

Overall, it looks like your heart is in the right place
and you are doing the right sort of things.

Keep it up!

Comment: everything you said was accurate and correct. i implemented all the changes. thank you

Comment: Also, `if not x`/`else` is harder to read than swapping the clauses to give `if x` - and we don't need `else` if the `if` branch returns.

Comment: yes, that was a dumb mistake of mine, thanks for pointing it out @TobySpeight